# Compare entered password with password in Oracle RightNow database

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, rightnow-crm

I have made a Windows Foundation Communication project which is connected with a RightNow CX database. For logging in I want to authenticate users by comparing the entered password with the corresponding password in the database. So the questions are:

1. Where can I find the passwords in the database;
2. How do I get access to the passwords?;
3. Is an encryption needed?

Comment: No cloud based service provider will let you compare passwords. that would encourage hacking. What you need to do in this case, is take the user id and the password, send it over to RightNow and get a token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only version of RightNow that supports something remotely like what you are attempting is 13.11 where RightNow can act as a SAML IDP.  Other than that, there is no way to leverage usernames and passwords within the Oracle RightNow Cloud to authenticate to another system.

As @abhi mentioned, there is no access (encrypted or not) to contact or account passwords in RightNow.